# How to add maven repository into zip file while building using maven in mule

Tags: java, maven, mule, mule-studio

How can I add the reference library in to my zip file while building with maven.
I am trying to achieve it through assembly as suggested in some blogs. But it didn't working for me. Please help me if it can achieve through or there is other way around. Here is the below code I am trying.

Added this in my pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>cs-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>mule</packaging>
<name>Mule cs-app Application</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <mule.version>3.6.1</mule.version>
    <mule.tools.version>1.0</mule.tools.version>
    <munit.version>3.6.0-BETA</munit.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                <inclusions>
                    <inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId></artifactId>
                    </inclusion>
                </inclusions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-resource</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>mappings/</directory>
                            </resource>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <!-- <testResources> <testResource> <directory>src/test/resources</directory> 
        </testResource> </testResources> -->
</build>

<!-- Mule Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <!-- Mule Transports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->
    <!-- Mule Modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.xquery</groupId>
                <artifactId>xqj-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependency added for mandrillapp -->
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung</groupId>
         <artifactId>lutung</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId> 
        <version>${mule.version}</version> 
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-mongo</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-devkit-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-interceptor-module</artifactId>
        <version>${munit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-pro</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.16</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-client</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.testng</groupId> <artifactId>testng</artifactId> 
        <version>6.8.8</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
    <!-- Spring data mongodb 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency> -->

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Central</id>
        <name>Central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-snapshots</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Snapshots Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven 2</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>


</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-release</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>

    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mule-plugin</id>
        <name>Mule Public Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

My assembly.xml

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>mule-config.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <useTransitiveFiltering>true</useTransitiveFiltering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>org.mule:mule-core</exclude>
                <exclude>org.mule.transports:mule-transport-*</exclude>
                <exclude>org.mule.modules:mule-module-*</exclude>
                <exclude>org.springframework:spring-*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: This is a mule app with external dependencies you want to zip together? There are special plugins to do this, see https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-esb-maven-tools , ```mule-app-maven-plugin``` should take care of it. Are you using it already? Can you share the entire pom?

Comment: Hi @afelisatti I am using it already. I have edited my question and pasted entire pom.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try after, removing `<scope>provided</scope>`  from the `<dependency>` tag.